# Iterating through pairs of files with glob

Tags: bash

I'm having a difficult time trying to iterate through a long set of files that I need to pair up to run through some process. I'd like to generate a bit of a batch file, pairing each set of matching files one per line. I've done this kind of thing before when it's a simple replacement (e.g. file1 = something.txt, file2 = something.csv). But in this case, the end of the file string is a random UUID, and I can't figure out how to get bash to properly expand the glob the second file.

Given a directory of files like this:

```
banana_pre-proc_b101a65a-31c7-5e4f-b433-bac4fb1efc1f.txt
banana_proc_a75b3a3e-7140-1cb6-2ad1-c10f7db6743f.txt
cherry_pre-proc_f5d0716f-c205-b0b4-5c63-d33755767de4.txt
cherry_proc_025ff6d5-534d-0020-5446-5da3ed04adc6.txt
kiwi_pre-proc_26075f3b-e3a2-fc1a-a741-615cacfc1a7e.txt
kiwi_proc_be1760f6-413d-edc0-1efc-a134b1b6bfbb.txt
peach_pre-proc_ecafbb30-3df0-6014-61ee-11d1d5745b53.txt
peach_proc_bb3ea3fc-671e-e024-6e61-06a2bc147363.txt
pear_pre-proc_c2db376f-f351-7141-114e-a2ebc3cfc410.txt
pear_proc_ccb2f16a-27cd-c70d-7aac-ce72c3af6575.txt
```

How can I get a file that looks like:

```
banana_pre-proc_b101a65a-31c7-5e4f-b433-bac4fb1efc1f.txt banana_proc_a75b3a3e-7140-1cb6-2ad1-c10f7db6743f.txt
cherry_pre-proc_f5d0716f-c205-b0b4-5c63-d33755767de4.txt cherry_proc_025ff6d5-534d-0020-5446-5da3ed04adc6.txt
kiwi_pre-proc_26075f3b-e3a2-fc1a-a741-615cacfc1a7e.txt kiwi_proc_be1760f6-413d-edc0-1efc-a134b1b6bfbb.txt
peach_pre-proc_ecafbb30-3df0-6014-61ee-11d1d5745b53.txt peach_proc_bb3ea3fc-671e-e024-6e61-06a2bc147363.txt
pear_pre-proc_c2db376f-f351-7141-114e-a2ebc3cfc410.txt pear_proc_ccb2f16a-27cd-c70d-7aac-ce72c3af6575.txt
```

I thought I could do something like

```
for f in *pre-proc_*txt; do echo "$f" "${f/-pre-proc_/-proc_}"; done
```

But that doesn't deal with the UUID at the end of the file. I've tried a few other iterations of this strategy too, but none get any closer.  What is the trick to doing this?  Obviously for a few files like this, I can just manually do it.  But, the actual set of files I need to process is quite long and apart from just pulling them all into a text doc and then using some Vim macro or something, I'm a bit baffled as to how to get Bash to expand the glob like I'm intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
for preproc in *_pre-proc*; do
  base=${preproc%_pre-proc*}
  proc=${base}_proc*
  echo $preproc $proc
done
```

We get a base name by stripping of the `_pre_proc<uuid>` part, and
then use the base name to find the matching `_proc` file.

Comment: Ahhh!  I see now.  Needed a sort of intermediate step to hold part of the filename as we build it.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This I think should be sufficient:

```sh
printf "%s %s\n" *[-_]proc_*.txt
```

Glob expansions are sorted and the pairs of files share the same prefix.

Comment: This is a great trick!  I like how simple and flexible this approach is.